# Difference between ccall and capi FFI calling conventions

Tags: haskell, ffi

I discovered that there are two calling conventions using [GHC's FFI](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ffi-chap.html): `ccall` and `capi`. The docs don't have much information about the two conventions. What is the difference between them, and when should I use each one? Is one faster than the other?

Comment: I clicked on the link and may I just say that the new GHC docs look marvellous!

Comment: I think the difference lies with the import of plain c-files and header files, but this is only guessing, I have actually never used the FFI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ccall` is the normal way. It works by directly linking against a symbol defined in a (usually written in C) library.

`capi` is a ghc extension that works on the C source level. That's why it can access things that don't exist at the ABI level, such as macros. (I don't know how it's implemented, but I would guess it generates a small C function wrapper, which it then compiles with a C compiler behind the scenes.)

I would use `ccall` where possible. It's part of the language standard and looks less "magical" in general.

Comment: Do you have any concrete reasons for preferring `ccall` over `capi`? C libraries are normally defined by their API, not ABI, and using `ccall` often causes problems when porting to exotic platforms (such as Android) that choose to implement some functions as macros that can be easily avoided by using `capi`. I've never encountered an issue caused by using `capi` over `ccall` (though that is probably just because people rarely use `capi` in the first place).